# Document List is not available in the application list

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a Sharepoint 2013 site, and my users want to be able to add document lists... unfortunately, when they access the "Add an application" interface, the only entry that is available is the good old regular list.

I have been able to create document list by myself using the REST API. However, nothing in the interface seems to expose that kind of features.

What should I do so that my users can create their own document list from the web interface ?

Comment: Add an app or Application? What is the permission? What is the site template?

Comment: Only those users can't see those templates? do you have those list templates in the List templates library (at site collection level?)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "Document Library" application if you have the "List Administrator" permission level (Commonly for the users in the group "Editor").
Give the users the permission, but you have to know that they can create not only Document Libraries applications, but any other type of application (list) too.